# How to compile using a long command with many options for ps2pdf?

Tags: texmaker

I'm using Texmaker and need to compile using `latex`, `biber`, `latex`, `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf`. If compiling from command line, doing

```bsh
latex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex
biber file.bcf
latex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex
latex -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex
dvips -o file.ps file.dvi
ps2pdf -dMaxSubsetPct#100 -dCompatibilityLevel#1.2 -dSubsetFonts#true -dEmbedAllFonts#true -dAutoFilterColorImages#false -dAutoFilterGrayImages#false -dColorImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dGrayImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dModoImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dDownsampleColorImages#false -dDownsampleGrayImages#false -dDownsampleMonoImages#false -dColorImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dPDFsettings#/prepress file.ps file.pdf
```

everything works fine. But when configuring a custom command in Texmaker like

```bsh
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|biber %.bcf|latex
-interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|dvips -o %.ps %.dvi|ps2pdf -dMaxSubsetPct#100
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.2 -dSubsetFonts#true -dEmbedAllFonts#true -dAutoFilterColorImages#false -dAutoFilterGrayImages#false -dColorImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dGrayImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dModoImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dDownsampleColorImages#false -dDownsampleGrayImages#false -dDownsampleMonoImages#false -dColorImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dPDFsettings#/prepress %.ps %.pdf|"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf
```

the creation of PDF fails. There is an error saying that the file cannot be found, but the message is gone too fast for me to entirely read it...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you don't want to pipe the output from one command to the next (using "|"), but just want to put the commands in sequence. Then ";" is the proper way to separate those.

Comment: Texmaker requires multiple commands to be separated by "|". Using latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|biber %.bcf|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|dvips -o %.ps %.dvi|ps2pdf %.ps %.pdf|"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf works and produces a PDF - but with poor quality which is why I need those options for ps2pdf.

Comment: @Wampo What TeX distribution are you using? If it's MiKTeX, install the `cm-super` package and your PDF files will have good quality also with `pdflatex`. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX and need above mentioned parameters so that ps2pdf doesn't compress my images. If I use these parameters from command line, the PDF is 300 kB larger in file size and displays the images as I want them to be displayed.

Comment: Remove the `interaction` so you can read the errors.

Answer (score 2):

In Texmaker, you can use Quickbuild Wizard to have your own sequence of commands to be executed on the .tex file

First step is to load the latex/dvips/ps2pdf commands in texmaker as shown below. Try zooming the browser to check the correct command line arguments

[image: Texmaker Configuration for latex/dvips/biber/ps2pdf]

After this build the sequence of commands as shown below 
[image: Order of Execution]

Once you press ok you will find the below commands in the user defined box

`latex -interaction=nonstopmode  %.tex|biber %.bcf|latex -interaction=nonstopmode  %.tex|latex -interaction=nonstopmode  %.tex|dvips -o %.ps %.dvi|ps2pdf -dMaxSubsetPct#100 -dCompatibilityLevel#1.2 -dSubsetFonts#true -dEmbedAllFonts#true -dAutoFilterColorImages#false -dAutoFilterGrayImages#false -dColorImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dGrayImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dModoImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dDownsampleColorImages#false -dDownsampleGrayImages#false -dDownsampleMonoImages#false -dColorImageFilter#/FlateEncode -dPDFsettings#/prepress %.ps`

Confirm your userdefined choice and Use the Quickbuild and Press VIEW PDF to see the pdf document.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The command itself works but will produce a PDF with bad image quality, too. I don't get why compiling from command-line works fine and letting Texmaker handle it won't give me satisfying results...

Comment: I have just added the commands inside texmaker configure menu (1st screen shot). Texmaker will execute the commands as if it were executed from 'cmd' window shell.